# slim.fully_connected: Using Tensor.shape to specify `num_outputs`

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-slim

I would like to use [`tf.slim.fully_connected`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L1585) for something like this:

```
conv_out = conv2d(...)
_, h, w, c = conv_out.shape
flat = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, h*w*c])
fc_out = fully_connected(flat, h*w*c)
```

However when I do this I get an error:

> ValueError: `num_outputs` should be int or long, got 49.

`h*w*c` is of type `tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.Dimension`.

Is there a way to do this, without knowing `whc` before hand, and without having to start a session to determine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `h*w*c` is of type `tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.Dimension`.

Correct, but `slim.fully_connected` checks for `isinstance(num_outputs, six.integer_types)`. It doesn't expect a `Dimension` instance.

That's why you should manually convert `h*w*c` to `int`:

```
fc_out = fully_connected(flat, int(h*w*c))
```